# One column containing value and variable

Tags: r

I read my data `mydata <-read.delim('/data.csv',comment.char="#")` which has only one column with values like `x=5`,`y=50`,`z=15`,`za=52`. How do I get the value of `x` in this case?

Comment: can you share a small sample of your data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use first:

```
data %>% separate(column_name, c("letter", "value"), "=")
```

To split in 2 columns, it will be easier to work then

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option in `base R`

```
with(mydata, sub("x\\=", "", grepl('x', col1, value = TRUE)))
```